Hurdle to implement periodic boundary conditions in Integer quantum hall effect on time-multiplex setup
I'm trying to compute the band structure of a system with periodic and open boundary conditions in MATLAB. The original code works fine and able to generate this :
.
which is representing open boundary conditions(code currently addresses this)
Now, I am modifying the code for Shift_Mat_Y matrix for periodic boundary conditions and I am aiming to obtain the following figure attached
,
but I am having trouble in it. Can someone help me identify what might be going wrong? Here is my complete code:
%% Parameters
NBands = 3;
Phi    = (2*pi)/NBands;
KxVec  = linspace(-pi,pi,100);
KyVec  = linspace(-pi,pi,100);

%% BS Matrix
T = 2*pi/8;
BS_Mat_X = zeros(2*NBands,2*NBands);

for i = 1:2*NBands
    for j = 1:2*NBands
        if i == j
            BS_Mat_X(i,j)  = cos(T);
        elseif abs(i-j) == NBands
            BS_Mat_X(i,j)  = 1i*sin(T);
            BS_Mat_X(j,i)  = 1i*sin(T);
        end
    end
end

BS_Mat_Y = BS_Mat_X;

%% Shift Matrix (Translation)
Shift_Mat_X = zeros(2*NBands,2*NBands,length(KyVec));
Shift_Mat_Y = zeros(2*NBands,2*NBands,length(KyVec));

for i = 1:NBands
    for j = 1:NBands
        if i == j
            Shift_Mat_X(i, j, :)               = exp(-1i * KxVec);
            Shift_Mat_X(i+NBands, j+NBands, :) = exp(1i * KxVec);
        end
    end
end

%% Open boundary condition
for i = 1:NBands
    for j = 1:NBands
        if (i - j) == -(NBands-1)
            Shift_Mat_Y(i, j, :)               = exp(1i * KyVec);
            Shift_Mat_Y(j+NBands, i+NBands, :) = exp(-1i * KyVec);
        elseif (i-j) == 1
            Shift_Mat_Y(i, j, :)               = 1;
            Shift_Mat_Y(j+NBands, i+NBands, :) = 1;
        end
    end
end

%% Phase Matrix
Phase_Mat = eye(2*NBands,2*NBands);
for i = 1:NBands
    Phase_Mat(i,i)               = exp(-1i*i*Phi);
    Phase_Mat(i+NBands,i+NBands) = exp(1i*i*Phi);
end

%% Time Evolution
EigenValues = zeros(length(KxVec),length(KyVec),2*NBands);
for i = 1:length(KxVec)
    for j = 1:length(KyVec)
        U = Shift_Mat_Y(:,:,j) * BS_Mat_Y * Shift_Mat_X(:,:,i) * Phase_Mat * BS_Mat_X;
        EigenValues(i,j,:) = sort(angle(eig(U)));
    end
end

%% Band structure
figure(1)
clf
hold on
for k = 1:2*NBands
    plot(KxVec./pi, EigenValues(:,:,k)./pi, 'b')
end
hold off
box on
xlabel('Kx/\pi')
ylabel('E/\pi')

figure(2)
clf
hold on
for k = 1:2*NBands
    surf(KxVec./pi, KyVec./pi, EigenValues(:,:,k)./pi, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
end
hold off
box on
xlabel('Kx')
ylabel('Ky')
view([-35 15])

I had made the following edits to address periodic boundary conditions just before the Phase-matrix calculation,mainly shifting the amplitude in +y and -y direction:
for a = 2:NBands-1
    Shift_Mat_Y(a, a-1, :) = 1;
end

for b = NBands:2*NBands-2
    Shift_Mat_Y(b, b+1, :) = 1;
end


please add a picture showing what your code actually does, which may not be as differnt from what you show as expected result
